# what are the best answers to these tests?

Tags: word-choice

I wanted to know your comments about answers of questions 51 and 52 in the bellow picture.
I think "Sat" is better for 52 and "Happy" for 51, but the answers in legal answer sheet are different, and I wanted to protest if answers were wrong.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: This looks like Off Topic "homework" to me, so I've voted to close accordingly. If you want a proper answer you need to ask a *specific question about a specific usage* - including in your question what research you've already done, and why you're still unable to understand the issue(s) involved.

Comment: @FumbleFingers it is not a homework I even have answer sheet but as I said the passage was not really obvious and clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**51:** Jack is responding to her wanting to get a job; he claims that his income makes this unnecessary, so the only characterization of her desire which makes sense is "silly".

**52:** There's **no answer** which makes this a coherent sentence. There are two possibilities; either

1. A subject (presumably *She*) has been omitted at the beginning. If this is the case you need a finite verb, and since the passage is cast in the past tense, it must be *sat*: *She sat around the house doing nothing and she began to get fat.*
   OR
2. The *and* in the middle is an error, and should be replaced with a comma. If this is the case, the front clause must act as an adverbial or adjectival adjunct. Only *Sitting* provides this syntax: *Sitting around the house doing nothing, she began to get fat.*

I suggest you point the error out to your examiners. If the exam was prepared by an ordinary overworked underpaid teacher, it's understandable; that sort of thing can happen, and your teacher will probably be happy to be corrected and impressed by your sharpness. If not, it will reflect well on both of you to *pretend* that it is an inadvertent error which your insight permits the teacher to correct!

But if the exam was prepared by a governmental or academic authority, or by a commercial operation, and the results of the exam are seen by anybody but the students and teachers themselves and used to make decisions regarding your academic and financial future, this is  disgraceful negligence and should be strongly protested.

Comment: I agree with StoneyB about the awkwardness of the given choices for blank number 52. I'm under the impression it is a commercial (or textbook) test which however was used over the years and possibly typed out instead of just photocopied. However, I'm not so sure a teacher would appreciate being told that there are mistakes in the text IF the test is of his/her production. They would certainly be if they are intelligent people, but not all teachers are...

Comment: for 51 : when their children left them she got bored but in the past she was happy so she needed to do sth to get out of boredom like finding a job but her husband told her that she doesn't need a job to be happy because she had money ( actually denied that she was bored ). can this explanation be true?

Comment: @XMen That's possible, but unlikely in context; I can't imagine even the most insensitive and self-centered husband telling his wife she's really "happy" when she plainly is not, though he might tell her she **should** be happy and has no real reason **not** to be happy. Does perhaps whatever word is used for *happy* in your language also mean [***fortunate***](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/fortunate)? That would explain your confusion. *Happy* is rarely used that way in contemporary English, though it once was common.

Comment: @Paola OP already announced an intention to 'protest'. I'm afraid there's a chance you're right about the teacher; but I think it strategically best to at least pretend to regard such things as inadvertent mistakes. I will modify my answer.

Comment: @StoneyB no it doesn't really mean fortunate but somehow they are related to each other , aren't they? and I didn't know that "Happy is rarely used that way in contemporary English, though it once was common." was a very useful point . Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Mr.questioner It's used in that sense in a very few contexts - "a *happy* chance", or "Oh, happy day!" - but otherwise it is old-fashioned and literary.

Answer (score 1):

For 51 I would choose "silly"and for the next one - "sitting", although with the "and" which follows later in the sentence it somehow does not sound quite right. But your two preferences would not be correct.

Comment: Thanks . Whay "Sat" is not true?

Comment: For "sat" to be correct, you need a subject at the beginning. Even then I would probably use a continuous tense instead of past simple.